# Arrays of arraylists in java related to infer generic type arguments suggestion in eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

This question is regarding arrays of arraylist.

When I write the code similar to this in eclipse, the eclipse gave suggestions on

a) Infer generic type arguments
b) supress warnings and allow this part of the code to be unchecked.

```
ArrayList<Integer> [] test = new ArrayList[];
```

In my code, I need to iterate over the arraylist and pick the numbers and I want the numbers to behave as ints always. So, do I have to get the intValue from Integer objects, in order for the code to work well. 
Is this a good idea to use arrays of arrayList. 
I suppressed the warning and sometimes, the code works well, and sometimes I think some problem which is difficult to identify.

So, what I want to know is

a) if there is any better way to do this?
b) Is this way always prone to errors?

Comment: We canot create the array for the generic type of ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use List of ArrayLists rather than arrays of arrayLists as we have to provide size for the arrays while defining.

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> test=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

If you want primitive `int` values , yes use `intValue()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Get GNU Trove primitive collections, and use `TIntArrayList[]`, which can be instantiated without generics.

This uses only about 1/3rd of the memory. Java Collections of primitive types are a performance sin.

Other than that, what is wrong with

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<>();
```

This may be less efficient, but does not yield warnings and will be just as performant.

Internally, `ArrayList` will use an `Object[]` for representation, so this is essentially the same as using `Object[][]`. An `Integer` uses 16 bytes + the reference, so you will use roughly (16+4)/4 = 5 times as much memory (on 32 bit, depending on the fill, it may be "only" 3 times as much in practise) as if you would be using `int[][]` or `TIntArrayList[]`.

Nevertheless, for a novice programmer `ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>` is probably the simples approach to get arrays-of-arrays and generics working.

Comment: Shouldn't we use the List interface?

Comment: I prefer using the `ArrayList` interface when I plan to use `get(int)`, to prevent someone from ever putting a `LinkedList` there and ruin performance. And I barely ever have use for linked lists, actually.